# Добавление заголовка в json ответа web api

Tags: json, веб-программирование, api, asp.net-core, get

Вопрос скорее всего простейший, но, к сожалению, многочасовые попытки применить все найденные в интернете решения не привели к успеху.
По образу и подобию туториалов майкрософт, создал стандартное API для доступа к базе. Метод Get в контролере

```
       // GET: api/Experts
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Expert>>> GetExpert()
    {
        return await _context.Experts.ToListAsync();
    }
```

возвращает:

```
[{"id":1,"fullName":"V P","competenceLevel":null,"audioGuide":[],"mentoring":[],"review":[]},
 {"id":2,"fullName":"D","competenceLevel":null,"audioGuide":[],"mentoring":[],"review":[]},]
```

Этот запрос необходимо обрабатывать в реакте на фронте, а для этого необходимо, чтобы запрос возращался в таком виде:

```
[Experts:{"id":1,"fullName":"V P","competenceLevel":null,"audioGuide":[],"mentoring":[],"review":[]},
{"id":2,"fullName":"D","competenceLevel":null,"audioGuide":[],"mentoring":[],"review":[]},]
```

Как правильно видоизменить исходную функцию?

Comment: Так же будут интересны комментарии от альтернативных путях воплощения задачи получения второго json.

Comment: а что мешает в reacte  видоизменить ответ?